# Regex to extract base64 encoded parts from email body from php imap

Tags: php, regex, base64

I have the following sting below, It's an e-mail body and I want to extract only the `base64` encoded files from it in PHP. I was thinking I could use regex to just extract the base64 parts so I could then decode them e.g.

```
preg_match('/Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\s(.*)\sContent-Type:/', $message['body'], $matches);

echo base64_decode($matches[0]);
```

However I'm not getting any matches as I don't think my regex is working. Ideally I want to capture each part which starts after 'Content-Transfer-Encoding:' and ends with another 'Content-Type:' part starting. My question is, how do I regex all the base64 parts? e.g.

`Content-Transfer-Encoding`: (capture this part as a match) Content-Type:

Below is part of the message and the full string can be found here:

> http://pastebin.com/A5XXnSaT
>
> --_004_D16F6E4A2986D34F9D752E3564EAC46F359618EFAPP1197ghakfplc_ Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_000_D16F6E4A2986D34F9D752E3564EAC46F359618EFAPP1197ghakfplc_" --_000_D16F6E4A2986D34F9D752E3564EAC46F359618EFAPP1197ghakfplc_ Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 SGksIFBsZWFzZSBmaW5kIHRoZSBhdHRhY2hlZCBQRlMgZXJyb3IgUmVwb3J0DQoKLS0tLS0tLS0t LQpCJlEgcGxjClJlZ2lzdGVyZWQgT2ZmaWNlOiBCJlEgSG91c2UsIENoZXN0bnV0IEF2ZW51ZSwg Q2hhbmRsZXJzIEZvcmQsIEVhc3RsZWlnaCwgSGFtcHNoaXJlLCBTTzUzIDNMRQpCdXkgT25saW5l IE5PVyBhdCB3d3cuZGl5LmNvbSBvciBmb2xsb3cgQiZRIG9uIEZhY2Vib29rIHd3dy5mYWNlYm9v...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Outputs 6 decoded parts

```
$result=[];
preg_match_all('/Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\s(.*?)\s--/', $message['body'], $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $base) {
    $result[] = base64_decode($base);
}

print_r($result);
```

Example: https://eval.in/438478

Comment: Not sure why but I get two empty arrays for the matches

Comment: Example output part of content because of eval.in restrictions. Run code in my answer in your project to see full result.

Comment: Add to remove the new line characters from my string and get it all on one line for it to work. Thanks for the help.